# count how many words from a word list appear in a cell

Tags: excel

Im trying to count the amount of times a word occurs in a string in excel, but im not sure how to do it. I found the formula =SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&Z$2:Z$20&","," "&A1&","))+0) in another post, but I can't seem to make it work for me.

data example (strings):

```
        text
1335    Nu standaard 3 dagen #Full #Membership bij #LACH , #dating voor #50plus http://t.co/7urme1Huhq http://t.co/ZzGWnKNdgx
1334    De 50plus cliché-poll vul hem in en we zien direct of de clichés waar zijn,
1282    #Koopkracht staat centraal in de campagne van #50Plus. Volgens mij maken veel ouderen zich zorgen over heel andere zaken. #PS2015
1278    #ps15 #50Plus: Dramatische gevolgen afschaffen ouderentoeslag http://t.co/nJW8kQRTtu Zie http://t.co/bFGtRDhF7e
1276    Campagnebussen in beeld. Mijn favoriet: de Fiat Babyboom van 50Plus. http://t.co/Wji8fL3gDp
1275    50Plus staat alleen in stelling over sociaal beleid http://t.co/79TF5PWN2j
1266    .@Struijlaard #50PLUS Zuid-Holland trekt met een camper de hele provincie door. Vandaag tot 17.00 uur in Leerdam. #PS15
1262    Stem #50PLUS op 18 maart !
1261    Boek van 98-jarige zangeres http://t.co/xxFjkTxYDY #vrouwen #50plus #muziek #Gog #Dings #Liessel
1257    @senfkarin kwam je op 50plus?
```

Word list:

```
achterlijk
bewogen
bovenkomen
brutaliteit
dramatisch
gehoorzamen
groen
illuminatie
incongruent
kwaadspreken
ontmoeting
ontredderd
recidiveren
roestig
ruw
secuur
steenkoud
tippelen
treffen
verbleken
verkijken
verlevendigen
vertillen
vorig
wezen
zorg
zwier
```

Comment: If only a single word can be found in the cell, but the occurs twice, do you want the formula to return **2** ??

Comment: I don't expect that to happen very often. Either way is fine, but of course it would be great if I understood what would happen in cases that the same word is mentioned multiple times. Did not consider this yet, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the commas are messing it up, it should be

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&Z$2:Z$20&" "," "&A1&" "))+0)
```

So it matches the whole word plus the spaces at each end, even when it is the first or last word in the cell.

Comment: Glad it helped (I haven't tested it in Dutch!)

Comment: I am working with it :). It works when you replace the comma with ";" in my version of excel.